# Javascript scroll activation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scroll

My friend made me a webpage to help me learn some Javascript, he made a page where the contents of each div became visible once the user scrolls past the top of the div. The problem is that the content shows up to late, so I want to make it activate the animation once the user has scrolled 80% down the section above it, or -20% of the next section.
Sorry for the long winded explanation, but it is rather hard to describe, please take a look at the jsfiddle and you will understand what I mean.

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wiggy/znbwhroq/3/)

```
    <script>

function scrollContent(){

//store the header as a variable
var header = document.getElementById("header");

//IMPORTANT NOTE ABOUT ARRAYS:
//the first item in an array isnt the "1"st itemm its the "0"th.
//so to select the first item, you say sections[0], to select the second item, you say sections[1] etc etc.

//get all of the elements with the class "section"
//and store them in an array
var sections = document.getElementsByClassName("section");

//do the same as above, for the "content" elements.
var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("content");

//get the height of the page
//which, because of our css, is also the height of one section
var height = window.innerHeight;

//get users position on the page
var ypos = window.pageYOffset; 

//which section the user is currently on
//we work this out by dividng the user's position on the page
//by the height of the actual page (which is the same height as one section)

//for example, if the user is 1000 pixels down and the page is 500 pixels high,
//1000 divided by 500 is 2, so they are on the second section.
//we wrap the sum in Math.floor() to round it down to the nearest whole number
var currentSection = Math.floor(ypos / height);

//stops the animation breaking when people try to scroll above the top of the page
if(currentSection < 0){
    currentSection = 0;
}



//loop through all of the sections
for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
    //if the section is currently in view
    if(i <= currentSection){
        //make the content viewable
        contents[i].style.opacity = "1";
    //if not
    } else {
        //hide the content
        contents[i].style.opacity = "0";
    }
}

}

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollContent);
scrollContent();

</script>
```

Comment: Add the javaScript code at least, please?

Comment: is the jsfiddle not working? I added the Javascript also, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the `var ypos` (user scroll position) to:

```
var ypos = window.pageYOffset + Math.floor(height * 0.2);
```

Where `* 0.2` is 20% of the `height`/`window.innerHeight` value. So it's really just adding a *buffer* of 20% of the height into the scroll position which allows the remainder of the (opacity) code to render *early*, so-to-speak.

You can change the `0.2` value to whatever you like to allow the content to come into display sooner or later during the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Add JS. Check your innerHeight property